# How to calculate previous month data on starting of next month in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I am using condition below to show data for current month only/previous month(if its new month started). 
let's say today is 3rd june so it should only give 1st an 2nd data,if its 10 it should give data from 1 to 9th,similarly it should be like this until month end but when there will be 1st of next month it should give data from previous month. the conditions I am using are giving blank data on every 1st. . Here is the condition I am using:

```
where Datestarted between CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT( DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1 
     AND 
    ADD_MONTHS(( CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT (DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1), 1) - 1
```

Comment: This condition returns full month of rows, but not what you want. And I don't get your rules, why do you want 1-2 for the 3rd of may, but 1-28 for the 28th?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to base your calculation on yesterday, not today:

```
where Datestarted between (CURRENT_DATE-1) - EXTRACT( DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE-1) + 1 
     AND 
   CURRENT_DATE-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe mean **previous month to date**?

```
Try this:
select
calendar_date
from
sys_calendar.calendar
where
calendar_date between cast((ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1)/100*100)+1 as DATE) and
  add_months(current_date,-1)-1
```

EDIT:  Based on your comments, let's try this:

```
SELECT
calendar_date
FROM
sys_calendar.CALENDAR
WHERE 
(EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) = 1 --previous month
 AND
    Calendar_Date BETWEEN CAST((ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, - 1)/100 * 100) + 1 AS DATE)
        AND CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE))
OR--current mtd
 (
 Calendar_Date BETWEEN CAST((CURRENT_DATE / 100 * 100) + 1 AS DATE)
        AND CURRENT_DATE - 1  
)
ORDER BY calendar_date
```

Comment: not previous moth to date. let's say today is 3rd june so it should only give 1st an 2nd data,if its 10 it should give data from 1 to 9th,similarly it should be like this until month end but when there will be 1st of next month it should give data from previous month. the conditions I am using are giving blank data on every 1st.

Comment: Then you're going to need to your original post to explain what you are trying to do, it's very unclear currently.

Comment: @user3438498, made some changes, see if that's what you're looking for.